# Command Line String Checking and argument passing (ImageMagick)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, imagemagick, string-comparison

I have this cool little snippet that I found, which adds a shadow to an image. (using imageMagick, i think..)

```
  image-shadow () {
  out=${1%.*}-shadow.${1#*.}
  in=$1
  echo "Converted file : $out"
  if [ ! -z $2 ] ; then 
    convert $in -frame $2 $out
    in=$out
  fi
  convert $in \( +clone -background black -shadow 60x5+3+3 \) \
    +swap -background transparent -layers merge +repage $out
  }
```

We use:

```
image-shadow test.png 0x0
```

to add 0x0 border, and 3x3 shadow, as defined inside the function...

Now, I have *-hd.png images, and *.png images .. And would like to add 3x3 shadows to the *.png and 6x6 to the *-hd.png (obviously, retina graphics..)

1- How can I compare the the image name, and decide

2- How can I pass the shadow size

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1.: Use find, it is really the Swiss army knife for such jobs:

```
find '(' -name '*.png' -and -not -name '*-hd.png' ')' -exec image-shadow '{}' 0x0 ';'
```

Of course, you'll have to save your function as a single shell file instead of a shell function, but this is desirable for code reuse anyway.

For 2.: Use another command line argument, which is referenced in the function as $3.

Comment: looks great! .. about 1) .. why do you use: '{}' ? What are these for? ... Wouldn't you normally save the result from find into a variable then use it?

Comment: Oh wait .. that's an option >_> .. sry about that, I can't get used to reading command line code.

Comment: Yes, the {} is passed into find and all. The find syntax is slightly tricky, but man find is a worthy read.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.png; do
  case "$f" in
    *-hd.png) shadow="6x6" ;;
    *) shadow="3x3" ;;
  esac
  image-shadow "$f" $shadow
dona
```